# "Trying to remove a child that doesn't exist" geting this error in react native while performing animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting a warning in React Native and i have no idea why i am geting this error.

I am trying to build a video controll , animation is working fine but after change in device orientation i am geting this "Trying to remove a child that doesn't exist" error warning and also the postion of controll is not at the expected place.

```
export const VideoPlayerControll = (
    {
      videoName,
      navigation
    }
    )=>{
      const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(null)

      const {width,height} = useWindowDimensions()

      const [topControllPosition, setTopControllPosition]= useState(new Animated.Value(25));
      const [rightControllPosition,setRightControllPosition] = useState(new Animated.Value(width-50))
      const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState(null);

      useEffect(()=>{
        Orientation.getOrientation(function(orientation){
          setOrientation(orientation)
        })
      },[])

      const triggerShowHide = useCallback(() => {
        console.log("triggerShowHide")
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);

        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(topControllPosition, {
            toValue: topControllPosition,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
            easing:Easing.linear
          }),
          Animated.timing(rightControllPosition, {
            toValue: rightControllPosition,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
            easing:Easing.linear
          }),
        ]).start();
      
        const hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(topControllPosition, {
              toValue: -50,
              duration: 500,
              useNativeDriver: true,
              easing:Easing.linear
            }),
            Animated.timing(rightControllPosition, {
              toValue: 800,
              duration: 500,
              useNativeDriver: true,
              easing:Easing.linear
            }),

          ]).start();
        }, VIDEO_CONTROLLS_HIDE_TIMEOUT);
      
        setTimeoutId(hideTimeout);
      },[orientation]);

      const onChangeOrientation = ()=>{
        if(orientation === PORTRAIT){
          Orientation.lockToLandscape()
          setOrientation(LANDSCAPE)

        }else if(orientation !== PORTRAIT){
          Orientation.lockToPortrait()
          setOrientation(PORTRAIT)
        }
        setTopControllPosition(new Animated.Value(25))
        setRightControllPosition(new Animated.Value((Dimensions.get("window").height-50)))
      }

      const onPressBackButton = ()=>{
        Orientation.lockToPortrait()
        navigation.goBack()
      }
    


    return (
      <Pressable onPress={triggerShowHide} style={{flex:1}}>
        <Animated.View style={{flex:1}}>
          <Animated.View 
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            transform:[{translateY:topControllPosition}],
            width:width
          }}>
            <View style={styles.topControllCont}>
              <Pressable 
              onPress={onPressBackButton}
              style={globalStyle.displayItemInRow}
              >
                <Ionicons 
                    name={"arrow-back"} 
                    size={28} 
                    color={themeColors.primaryColor}
                />
                <Text style={{color:themeColors.primaryColor, marginLeft:10}}>{shortenName(videoName, 30) }</Text>
              </Pressable>
              <Pressable 
              style={globalStyle.displayItemInRow}
              >
                <Ionicons 
                    name={"share-social-sharp"} 
                    size={28} 
                    color={themeColors.primaryColor}
                />
              </Pressable>
            </View>
          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.View
          style={{
            position:"absolute",
            transform: [{ translateY: height/2-50}, {translateX:rightControllPosition}],
          }}
          >
            <Pressable 
              onPress={onChangeOrientation}
              style={styles.contBtn}
              >
              <MaterialCommunityIcons 
                  name={"phone-rotate-landscape"} 
                  size={24} 
                  color={themeColors.primaryColor}
              />
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable 
            style={styles.contBtn}
            >
              <MaterialCommunityIcons 
                  name="cellphone-screenshot"
                  size={24} 
                  color={themeColors.primaryColor}
              />
            </Pressable>
          </Animated.View>
        </Animated.View>
      </Pressable>
    )
}
```

I am using react-native-orientation-locker to lock the device oreientation. animation is working fine if the the device orientation is fixed to one oreientation. it does not work after orientation change.I am using below function change the oreientation.

```
      const onChangeOrientation = ()=>{
        if(orientation === PORTRAIT){
          Orientation.lockToLandscape()
          setOrientation(LANDSCAPE)

        }else if(orientation !== PORTRAIT){
          Orientation.lockToPortrait()
          setOrientation(PORTRAIT)
        }
        setTopControllPosition(new Animated.Value(25))
        setRightControllPosition(new Animated.Value((Dimensions.get("window").height-50)))
      }
```

and triggerShowHide function to show the controll and after sometime hide the controll

```
      const triggerShowHide = useCallback(() => {
        console.log("triggerShowHide")
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);

        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(topControllPosition, {
            toValue: topControllPosition,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
            easing:Easing.linear
          }),
          Animated.timing(rightControllPosition, {
            toValue: rightControllPosition,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true,
            easing:Easing.linear
          }),
        ]).start();
      
        const hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
          Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(topControllPosition, {
              toValue: -50,
              duration: 500,
              useNativeDriver: true,
              easing:Easing.linear
            }),
            Animated.timing(rightControllPosition, {
              toValue: 800,
              duration: 500,
              useNativeDriver: true,
              easing:Easing.linear
            }),

          ]).start();
        }, VIDEO_CONTROLLS_HIDE_TIMEOUT);
      
        setTimeoutId(hideTimeout);
      },[orientation]);
```

Answer (score 0):

PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(value);

In my case value was NaN.

Comment: The problem is not related to push notification